# Counting connected graphs

Tags: python, recursion, combinations, graph-theory, combinatorics

I'm trying to count the number of simple, connected graphs with exactly K
edges and N distinctly labelled vertices. I've written this code below, but it doesn't seem to work.

The idea is that this kind of graph would have no isolated vertices, so I
do this for N vertices and K edges.

```
Connected(N,K):
1) Total = all possible graphs, including disconnected ones.
2) Disconnected = Sum from i=1 to i=N-1 [(Connected(i,K)*(number of ways to
    choose i vertices from all N vertices)]
3) return Total-Disconnected
```

Python code:

```
#c dict just stores previous combinations
c = {}    

def answer(N, K):
    ways = connected(N, K)
    return str(ways)

#number of simple graphs using exactly n vertices and k edges. no isolated vertices
def connected(n, k):
    if k < n-1:
        return 0
    edges = n*(n-1)/2
    if k > edges:
        return 0

    #number of all possible graphs with n vertices and k edges
    ways = choose(edges, k)

    #subtract number of graphs that are not connected
    for i in range(1, n):
        ways -= connected(i, k)*choose(n, i)
    return ways

#calculates nCk
def choose(n, k):
    key = str(n)+","+str(min([k,n-k]))+"/"+str(max([k,n-k]))
    if key in c:
        return c[key]
    else:
        top = fact(n)
        bottom = fact(k)*fact(n-k)
        ans = top/bottom
        c[key] = ans
        return ans

#factorial
def fact(num):
    ret = 1
    for i in range(2,num+1):
        ret *= i
    return ret
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include: What exactly doesn't work? Do you get an error? Did you get incorrect output? What output do you expect?

Comment: As a side note, you may want to take a look at [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/): it's a powerful library for dealing with graphs and graph theory.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula for Disconnected is actually not correct.

Let's label the vertices 1, 2, ..., N. In your formula, the term:

[(Connected(i,K)*(number of ways to choose i vertices from all N vertices)]

is supposed to calculate the number of graphs such that the connected component of the vertex 1 contains i vertices. But this product only gives the number of possible connected components. For every such choice of connected component, there are still a lot of ways to arrange edges among the rest (N - i) vertices.

In order to get a correct formula, you should take also the number of edges in the connected component into account.

Let Conn(i, j) be the number of connected graphs with i labeled vertices and exactly j edges. Then we have:

choose(N * (N - 1) / 2, K) = sum (i = 1 to N, j = 0 to K) choose(N - 1, i - 1) * Conn(i, j) * choose((N - i) * (N - i - 1) / 2, K - j)

The left hand side is the total number of graphs with N vertices and K edges. The summand of the right hand side is the number of graphs with N vertices, K edges, and such that the connected component of vertex 1 has i vertices and j edges.

Further explanation for the summand: you first choose i - 1 vertices out of the N - 1 vertices other than vertex 1, then multiply by the number of ways to form a connected graph with i vertices and j edges, and finally add any K - j edges from the remaining N - i vertices.

From this formula you should be able to write a DP algorithm to calculate all the numbers Conn(i, j).

Although this might be slow, it gives you correct answers. You can think about better algorithms later.